# How is $\{\mu (U): A^{-1} \subset U, U \text{ is open}\}=\{ \mu (U^{-1}): A \subset U, U \text{ is open}\}$?

Tags: measure-theory, topological-groups, haar-measure

I am reading these [notes](http://www.math.uchicago.edu/~may/VIGRE/VIGRE2010/REUPapers/Gleason.pdf) by Jonathan Gleason on the *Existence and Uniqueness of the Haar Measure*. On page no. 5 (Proof of Proposition 4.1, STEP: 2), I am not able to understand why
$$
\{\mu (U): A^{-1} \subseteq U, U \text{ is open}\}=\{ \mu (U^{-1}): A \subseteq U, U \text{ is open}\}.
$$
Here $A$ is a measurable subset of a topological group $G$, $U$ is open in $G$, and $\mu$ is a Haar measure on $G$. I have read the lemmas and definitions before the propositions but I couldn't get it. I'm sure it is something trivial, though; any help would be appreciated!

Comment: You have that $U$ is open if, and only if, $U^{-1}$ is open.

Comment: But does that mean $\mu(U) = \mu(U^{-1})$? If so, how?

Comment: Sorry, I was not able to comment earlier. However, I see your question is answered in the meantime.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just before the mentioned assertion, it is said that "$A^{-1}\subseteq U$ and $U$ is open if and only if $A\subseteq U^{-1}$ and $U^{-1}$ is open". Therefore, we have 
$$\tag{*}  \left\{\mu\left(U\right),A^{-1}\subseteq U, U\mbox{ is open}  \right\}=
\left\{\mu\left(U\right),A\subseteq U^{-1}, U^{-1}\mbox{ is open}  \right\}.$$
Now, as user342207 pointed out, $U$ is open if and only if $U^{-1}$ is open. Accounting the fact that $\left(U^{-1}\right)^{-1}=U$, we thus have 
\begin{align}
\left\{\mu\left(U\right),A\subseteq U^{-1}, U^{-1}\mbox{ is open}  \right\}&=\left\{\mu\left(\left(\color{red}{ U^{-1}} \right)^{-1}    \right),A\subseteq \color{red}{ U^{-1}},\color{red}{ U^{-1}}\mbox{ is open}  \right\}\\
&=\left\{\mu\left(\left(\color{red}{ V} \right)^{-1}    \right),A\subseteq \color{red}{ V},\color{red}{V}\mbox{ is open}  \right\}.
\end{align}

Comment: Thank you, that really clarifies my question!